# ASP.NET MVC - Can't set overrideable property = nothing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Let's say I have the following entities:

```
Public Class Dodo
    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property Mother As DodoMother
End Class

Public Class DodoMother
    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

I need to be able to set Dodo.Mother as nothing sometimes once it's been set.

I.e.

```
Dim ndodo as dodo = db.Dodos.find(1)
ndodo.Mother = nothing
db.SaveChanges()
```

When I execute the above code, I don't get an error or an exception or anything to indicate the statement hasn't worked. The ndodo object doesn't seem to set Mother to null and the DB doesn't get updated.

Am I doing something wrong? 
I also tried adding db.Entry(ndodo).State = EntityState.Modified but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Id property to the Dodo for the DodoMother and set that to nothing.

```
Public Property MotherId as Integer?
```

Your property 'Mother' is a Navagation property.  Navagation properties are not part of the database tables, they are part of your entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JLH :)

```
Public Property MotherID() As Nullable(Of Integer)

Public Overridable Property Mother() As DodoMother
```

and the following code to delete the Mother

```
Dim ndodo as dodo = db.Dodos.find(1)
ndodo.MotherID = nothing
db.SaveChanges()
```